# 2D matrix Node insertion and deletion issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am storing the id of the nodes in a 2-D matrix and when i delete or insert a node in b/w then the node after that updated node doesn't itself automatically get updated means the Id.
What should i do in this case.

Main functions:-

```js
click = (row, col) => {

    console.log("dontTriggerClick", dontTriggerClick);
    if (dontTriggerClick) {
      dontTriggerClick = false;
      return;
    }
    var { logic } = this.props;

    console.log("logic", this.props);

    const { currentProgramGuide } = logic;

    var todo = "current";

    logic.insertState = false;

    const { type } = drawing.board[row][col];

    console.log("type", type);

    if (type === "blank" || type === "hand" || type === "highlighted_hand")
      todo = "blank";
    if (todo === "current") {
      logic.active = [row, col];

      console.log("click current");

      drawing = ProgramToDrawing(
        logic.program,
        logic.end,
        logic.currentProgramGuide,
        logic.active,
        this.add,
        logic.insertState,
        this.insertNode,
        this.deleteNode
      );
      var logicState = {};
      // logicState['type'] = this.state.currentLogicScreen;
      // logicState['state'] = logic;
      console.log("NOW ZOOM  3", this.props);
        IDIS=`${row}${col}`
      // idss.push(`${row}-${col}`);
      //  logic.ids=idss;


      this.props.update(logic);
    } else if (todo === "blank") {
      console.log("clickfun blank");
      console.log("[-1, -1]");
      logic.active = [-1, -1];

      drawing = ProgramToDrawing(
        logic.program,
        logic.end,
        logic.currentProgramGuide,
        logic.active,
        this.add,
        logic.insertState,
        this.insertNode,
        this.deleteNode
      );
      var logicState = {};
      logicState["type"] = this.state.currentLogicScreen;
      logicState["state"] = logic;
      console.log("NOW ZOOM  4", this.props);

      this.props.update(logic);
    }
  };
add = (type) => {
    console.log("add fun");

    console.log("add fun type", type);
    if (type == "repeat") {
      this.setState({ readyForSimulation: type });
      sessionStorage.setItem("programEnd", type);
    }

    if (dontTriggerClick) {
      console.log("dontTriggerClick");
      dontTriggerClick = false;
      return;
    }

    var { logic } = this.props;

    logic.active = [-1, -1];

    console.log("ANKIT 222", type);

    // console.log("logic.program new", logic.program, type)

    if (
      type === "end_variable" ||
      type === "end_sensor" ||
      type === "end_condition" ||
      type === "end_if" ||
      type === "end_loop" ||
      type === "repeat"
    )
      logic.currentProgramGuide--;
    else {
      var toPush = { type: type, state: {} };

      console.log("logic.program", logic.program);
      console.log("logic.currentProgramGuide", logic.currentProgramGuide);
      console.log("toPush", toPush);

      if (
        type === "variable" ||
        type === "sensor" ||
        type === "condition" ||
        type === "loop"
      )
        toPush.subprogram = [];
      this.recurseAdd(logic.program, logic.currentProgramGuide, toPush);
      if (
        type === "variable" ||
        type === "sensor" ||
        type === "condition" ||
        type === "loop"
      )
        logic.currentProgramGuide++;
    }

    console.log("addfun, ");

    console.log(
      "addfun : logic.currentProgramGuide ",
      logic.currentProgramGuide
    );

    console.log("addfun :  logic.active, ", logic.active);

    drawing = ProgramToDrawing(
      logic.program,
      logic.end,
      logic.currentProgramGuide,
      logic.active,
      this.add
    );
    var logicState = {};
    logicState["type"] = this.state.currentLogicScreen;
    logicState["state"] = logic;
    console.log("NOW ZOOM  5", this.props);

    this.props.update(logic);
  };
  insertNode = (type) => {
    console.log("insertNode");
    var { logic } = this.props;
    if (!logic.insertState) {
      logic.insertState = true;
    } else {
      logic.insertState = false;
      var temp = drawing.activeParentRef[drawing.activeIndex];
      var toPush = { type: type, state: {} , id: IDIS};
      if (
        type === "variable" ||
        type === "condition" ||
        type === "sensor" ||
        type === "loop"
      )
        toPush.subprogram = [];
      drawing.activeParentRef[drawing.activeIndex] = toPush;
      for (
        let i = drawing.activeIndex + 1;
        i < drawing.activeParentRef.length;
        i++
      ) {
        var temp2 = drawing.activeParentRef[i];
        drawing.activeParentRef[i] = temp;
        temp = temp2;
      }
      if (temp) drawing.activeParentRef.push(temp);
      logic.active = [-1, -1];
    }
    console.log("logic.program", logic.program);
    drawing = ProgramToDrawing(
      logic.program,
      logic.end,
      logic.currentProgramGuide,
      logic.active,
      this.add,
      logic.insertState,
      this.insertNode,
      this.deleteNode
    );
    var logicState = {};
    logicState["type"] = this.state.currentLogicScreen;
    logicState["state"] = logic;
    console.log("NOW ZOOM  6", this.props);

    this.props.update(logic);
  };
  deleteNode = () => {
    console.log("deleteNode");
    var { logic } = this.props;
    if (
      drawing.activeParentRef.length - 1 == drawing.activeIndex &&
      (drawing.activeRef.type === "variable" ||
        drawing.activeRef.type === "sensor" ||
        drawing.activeRef.type === "condition" ||
        drawing.activeRef.type === "loop")
    ) {
      let currentProgramGuide = 0,
        temp = logic.program;
      while (
        temp != drawing.activeParentRef &&
        currentProgramGuide < logic.currentProgramGuide
      ) {
        temp = temp[temp.length - 1].subprogram;
        currentProgramGuide++;
      }
      if (currentProgramGuide < logic.currentProgramGuide)
        logic.currentProgramGuide = currentProgramGuide;
    }
    alert(drawing.activeIndex)
    drawing.activeParentRef.splice(drawing.activeIndex, 1);
    logic.active = [-1, -1];

    console.log("deleteNode fun ");
    drawing = ProgramToDrawing(
      logic.program,
      logic.end,
      logic.currentProgramGuide,
      logic.active,
      this.add,
      logic.insertState,
      this.insertNode,
      this.deleteNode
    );
    var logicState = {};
    logicState["type"] = this.state.currentLogicScreen;
    logicState["state"] = logic;

    this.props.update(logic);

  };
```

Redux Logic:-

```js
const logicSelection = (state = logic, action) => {


    var { payload } = action

    switch (action.type) {


        case 'LOGIC_SELECTION':
            var { program, end, insertState, offset, scale, currentProgramGuide, active, bottomPanel } = payload
            console.log("OFFSET KHUSHBOO", offset)
            var data = { ...state, program, end, insertState, offset, scale, currentProgramGuide, active, bottomPanel }
            sessionStorage.setItem('logic', JSON.stringify(data));
            return data;

        case 'LOGIC_RESET':
            console.log("LOGIC PAYLOAD", payload)

            var { program, end, insertState, offset, scale, currentProgramGuide, active, bottomPanel } = payload
            var data = { ...state, program, end, insertState, offset, scale, currentProgramGuide, active, bottomPanel }
            sessionStorage.setItem('logic', JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log("LOGIC DATA", data)

            return data;



        default:
            sessionStorage.setItem('logic', JSON.stringify(state));
            return state;
    }
}
```

I am only inserting Id when the node is inserted but i cant find a way to update the Id when deleting or inserting node again